# Getting scroll position with sencha architect extjs

Tags: extjs, scroll

I have been trying to get the scroll position of a tree grid in and ext.js application using sencha architect. Originally I wanted to keep the scroll position after a reload so when a user deletes a post it will scroll back to that same spot after reload. I have attempted to use various methods I have searched for but nothing is working. I'm currently testing by having a java script timeout function give me the scroll position after a few seconds, long enough for me to scroll down and console.log the position but it gives me nothing and I'm not showing anything but zero when I go into the dom and look at the tree view object. I have already tried the following

```
1st: var newcompheight = comboboxeample.getHeight();

2nd:  getScroll: function() {
    var me = this,
        dom = me.dom,
        doc = document,
        body = doc.body,
        docElement = doc.documentElement,
        left, top;

    if (dom === doc || dom === body) {
        // the scrollLeft/scrollTop may be either on the body or documentElement,
        // depending on browser. It is possible to use window.pageXOffset/pageYOffset
        // in most modern browsers but this complicates things when in rtl mode because
        // pageXOffset does not always behave the same as scrollLeft when direction is
        // rtl. (e.g. pageXOffset can be an offset from the right, while scrollLeft
        // is offset from the left, one can be positive and the other negative, etc.)
        // To avoid adding an extra layer of feature detection in rtl mode to deal with
        // these differences, it's best just to always use scrollLeft/scrollTop
        left = docElement.scrollLeft || (body ? body.scrollLeft : 0);
        top = docElement.scrollTop || (body ? body.scrollTop : 0);
    } else {
        left = dom.scrollLeft;
        top = dom.scrollTop;
    }

    return {
        left: left,
        top: top
    };

3rd: var test = window.pageYOffset;
```

I have also attempted to setting the keepscroll position property in Sencha architect to true  and other things I have googled but nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `treeGrid.getEl().getScrollTop()`?

Comment: Yea that helped. I tried something similar that wasn't working. I think I was passing in the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
treeGrid.getEl().getScrollTop()
```